# How to exit APK from shell

Tags: android, shell, apk, exit

I know how to start an APK from the shell using this command:
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n package name/activity name

Is there a way to quit the apk using shell commands? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
adb shell am kill com.blah.foo
```

From help docs: "am kill: Kill all processes associated with PACKAGE.  Only kills processes that are safe to kill -- that is, will not impact the user experience."

In other words: If you are actively using the application this will not kill it. It will only kill an application that is ready to be killed.

So if you wish to kill an application that is actively running use:

```
adb shell am force-stop com.blah.foo
```

This will close it without regard to what it affects

Comment: It's `am` that says that, and mine, on a 3.2 device, says it as well.

Comment: Strange. I've tried this on a rooted 2.3.7 phone as well as a rooted Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.3. Perhaps it only works on rooted devices?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I just used ps to find the PID of the process.
Then I used kill [pid] to kill that process.

This worked, but if there is any other way, help would be appreciated!